# How to convert saved model from NCHW to NHWC?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I trained my NCHW model on GPU and saved the best state.
I now want to make the inference on CPU, which apparently only support NHWC (I get an error mentionning that).
Do I have to retrain my model with NHWC, or is there a way to convert my model ?

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same situation, seeing errors like this when trying to run `model.predict` on my GPU trained model on an instance with only CPU available:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU
```

I eventually discovered that on Intel CPUs, one can successfully apply a model to data in NCHW format so long as MKL is enabled. With pip, one can install MKL enabled tensorflow with:

```
pip install intel-tensorflow
```

You can check that it is enabled (in tensorflow 2.3) with:

```
tf.python._pywrap_util_port.IsMklEnabled()
```

Comment: beautiful. confirming above works, tested with `intel/intel-optimized-tensorflow:2.8.0-jupyter`.  inference running with pretrained model containing channel-first layers.  Assuming no one updates the default `tf.keras.backend.image_data_format()` value which is `channels_last`, there is no need to call `set_image_data_format('channels_last')`!

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the most straight forward method is to use "intel-optimized tensorflow" as proposed by @jdmcbr

If above is not an option, you can consider converting the model to ONNX format first and then back to Tensorflow.

For example if you have a keras model file `keras_model.h5`
you can convert your model from Keras to ONNX to Tensorflow format with below 2 commands:

```
python -m tf2onnx.convert --keras keras_model.h5 --output model.onnx
onnx-tf convert --infile model.onnx --outdir updated_tf_model
```

If above errors out, you can attempt to convert from Keras to Tensorflow first:

```
python keras_to_tf.py keras_model.h5 tf_model
python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model tf_model --output model.onnx
onnx-tf convert --infile model.onnx --outdir updated_tf_model
```

`keras_to_tf.py` content:

```
import sys
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
keras_model_file = sys.argv[1]
tf_model_folder = sys.argv[2]
model = load_model(keras_model_file)
model.save(tf_model_folder)
```

Once you have the tensorflow model in folder `updated_tf_model`, then inference can performed, sample inference code snippet provided below.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

my_input_shape = (1,2,3,4) # modify accordingly
input_tensor_name = 'input_abc' # modify accordingly
output_tensor_name ='output_abc' # modify accordingly

batch_data = np.random.rand(*my_input_shape).astype(np.float32)
batch_data = tf.constant(batch_data,name=input_tensor_name)

model_folder = sys.argv[1]
loaded = tf.saved_model.load(model_folder)
model_fn = loaded.signatures['serving_default']
output_dict = model_fn(batch_data)
output  = output_dict[output_tensor_name]
print(output.shape)
```

above was tested using:
docker container: `tensorflow/tensorflow:2.8.0`
py libs: `google==3.0.0 tf2onnx==1.12.0 onnx-tf==1.10.0 tensorflow_probability==0.15.0 SimpleITK==2.1.1.2 scikit-image==0.19.3`

--

note 1. As you can see i did not provide the last step of converting Tensorflow to Keras model.  I think it is possible to convert tensorflow back to keras model, but you'll need to get the weight out from the tensorflow model object or edit pb files.  Please do post your solution if you figure out how to extract the weight per layer from Tensorflow model and set them back to keras layers.

note 2. there are 2 unmaintained libraries which by the name of them, seems like they should be able to convert the models from NCHW to NHWC.  I was unable to install them successufully.
https://github.com/gmalivenko/onnx2keras
https://github.com/onnx/keras-onnx